# Character spacing Control for WP7 Silverlight

Tags: windows-phone, custom-controls, windows-phone-7.1

Is there a way of changing the Character Spacing on Windows Phone 7?

if there is no built in way, has somebody made a control?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158199/how-to-change-character-spacing-in-xaml-in-a-textbox

Comment: they are related questions but i'm talking about Windows Phone 7 application and that question was talking about WPF

Comment: Since silverlight is a subset of WPF this should be kinda related - if there is no such option, then it's just not available in this form in SL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`FontStretch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontstretch%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), or transform your TextBlock to suit your needs.