# WP7 How to reduce the letter spacing in a TextBlock

Tags: windows-phone-7, kerning

Is it possible to reduce the letter spacing between characters in a text block?

Thank you

Thomas

Comment: possible duplicate of [Character spacing Control for WP7 Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441161/character-spacing-control-for-wp7-silverlight)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that kerning is supported on Windows Phone :-

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/5bd5c3c2-b9a0-4adf-a760-dab17abad157

A custom solution might be the following :-

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danteg/archive/2009/02/27/a-silverlight-textblock-with-tracking-surely-you-jest.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, I look at it immediatly.

Comment: May I precise that the text block is the header of a panorama control

Comment: Hello I tried to implement the solution that is in the post, but it is impossible to set the padding with a negative thickness, so actually I can increase the letter spacing but I wanted to decrease it...