# CharacterSpacing for WPF TextBlock

Tags: wpf, textblock

Since Silverlight 5 TextBlock have a CharacterSpacing property allowing to add extra space between characters. Is there a way to do the same thing in WPF ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158199/how-to-change-character-spacing-in-xaml-in-a-textbox

Comment: I agree that this is the same question than in the linked post. But since the property has been added to Silverlight, I was asking if an equivalent has been added to WPF too.

Comment: did you ever get an answer? I would like to know as well.