# spacing between characters in textbox / richtextbox wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, richtextbox, spacing

I need to have spaces between characters in textbox/richtextbox. For example,
"abcdef" should be displayed as "a b c d e f".

Also, why I am including richtextbox because I learned that it is not possible to color specific part of text in TextBox but it can be done in richtextbox(using TextPointer)

I am planning to have this textbox/richtextbox as a user control.

Is there any default way(any properties) to do it. Or Can I create a data template or something to achieve this behavior? So that when I move the cursor between the characters, the spaces in-between shouldn't be counted/considered.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158199/how-to-change-character-spacing-in-xaml-in-a-textbox

Comment: @Lennart, I am using data binding for the text. I don't know much about glyphs but learned that using glyphs will complicate your code.